# Show that there is a unique polynomial of degree at most $2k+1$ such that $p^{[j]}(x_1)=a_j \text{ and } p^{[j]}(x_2)=b_j \text{ for } j=0,\dots, k.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, interpolation

> Let $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$ and let $(a_0, \dots, a_k), (b_0, \dots, b_k)$ be $(k+1)$-tuples of real numbers. Show that there is a unique polynomial of degree at most $2k+1$ such that
>   $$p^{[j]}(x_1)=a_j \text{ and } p^{[j]}(x_2)=b_j \text{ for } j=0,\dots, k.$$
>
> [Consider the polynomials $(x-x_1)^k (x-x_2)^{k+1}$, $(x-x_1)^{k+1}(x-x_2)^k$ and argue by induction.]

Any help with this exercise?

Comment: Hint: Prove it for all $b_i=0$ first, which essentially means that $p(x)=(x-x_2)^{k+1}q(x)$. Then prove the general case from the special case

Comment: And, of course, you require $x_1\neq x_2.$